# missing pie chart and screenshot- serenity report from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I installed Thucydides Plugin to display reports but unfortunately pie charts and screenshots doesn't appear. How to solve this problem?
Jenkins is installed on Debian 8.

Comment: You can check ExtentReports and ExtentX. As good reporting can get.